# SELECT WHERE COUNT = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

Table `LESSON` has fields `LessonDate, MemberId` (Among others but only these two are relevant)

In English: Give me a list of the dates on which students that have only ever taken 1 class, took that class.

I have tried a number of things. Here's my latest attempt:

```
SELECT LessonDate 
FROM LESSON 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(MemberId) GROUP BY (MemberId)) = 1
```

Just keeps returning SQL errors. Obviously, the syntax and logic are off.

Comment: Your question is being marked down as you have not demonstrated that you have researched this problem very much. You might want to look at [This article on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and perform some basic searches before you actually post your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to keep my question clear and concise. I think that it's a bit unfair, I did do a lot of research and try many things before asking, but I realized that I didn't know what I needed to make it work. In this case it was the HAVING clause, which I have never seen before. You don't know what you don't know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The query may seem a little counter-intuitive at first.  You need to group by `MemberId` to get the students who only took one class:

```
select max(l.LessonDate) as LessonDate
from Lesson l
group by l.MemberId
having count(*) = 1;
```

Because there is only one class for the student, `max(l.LessonDate)` is that date.  Hence this does what you want:  it gets all the dates for members who only took one class.

Your line of thinking is also pretty close.  Here is the query that I think you were looking for:

```
SELECT LessonDate 
FROM LESSON 
WHERE MemberId in (SELECT l2.MemberId
                   FROM Lesson l2
                   GROUP BY l2.MemberId
                   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
                  );
```

This approach is more generalizable, if you want to get the dates for members that have 2 or 3 rows.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much! Was the "l2" thing really necessary? What is that called?

Comment: @pownassis . . . The `l2` is not necessarily in this query.  It is called a "table alias" and is just used to distinguish the table in the subquery from the table in the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into `SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... HAVING` There is a lot of documentation available online by searching `GROUP BY` e.g. [This article](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

The following SQL groups by `MemberId` which I thnk is wrong as you want to count the number of member id's,

```
SELECT
    LessonDate
    , MemberId 
    , COUNT(*) AS Lesson_Count
FROM 
    Lesson 
GROUP BY
    LessonDate
    , MemberId 
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 1
```

The above query will give you a list of "dates", "members", and the number of lessons taken on that date by that "member". I don't think you need to have the aggregate function (`COUNT(*) AS Lesson_Count`) as part of the select statement but it's often "nice to have" to give you the confidence that your results are as you would expect.

Your query is actually failing because the subquery doesn't have a `FROM` statement but the above is better practice:

```
SELECT LessonDate 
FROM LESSON 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(MemberId) FROM Lesson GROUP BY (MemberId)) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(LessonDate) as Lesson_date,MemberId from Lesson group by MemberId having Lesson_Date=1
```

or

```
select * from 
(
select *,rn=Row_number()over(partition by LessonDate order by MemberId) from Lesson
)
where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
SELECT LessonDate
FROM LESSION L
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LESSION WHERE MemberId=L.MemberId)=1
```

Comment: Thanx Wibble, I'm quite a noob here :)