# SQL query to ignore multiple rows that form a pattern?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to make my SQL query ignore consecutive rows that are forming a pattern?

For example,

`SELECT timestamp, url FROM api_table WHERE user="user1"`

| timestamp | url | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:00 | /v1/home | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:02 | /application/app/test1 | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:02 | /application/dev2/page | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:03 | /application/useless/test3 | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:10 | /v1/home | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:12 | /application/app/test1 | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:12 | /application/dev2/page | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:13 | /application/useless/test3 | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:15 | /index.php | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:15 | /features/newest/list.php | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:16 | /v1/home | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:17 | /application/app/test1 | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:17 | /application/dev2/page | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:18 | /application/useless/test3 | user1 |
| ... | ... |  |

There is a pattern of four consecutive rows (from **url=/v1/home** to **url=application/useless/test3** rows) scattered across the table and causes noise. The real useful rows are only these two:

| timestamp | url | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:15 | /index.php | user1 |
| 2021-01-01 00:45:15 | /features/newest/list.php | user1 |

I tried to use regex to extract and then exclude. However, the downside is the query will also ignore any future valid URLs that somehow match the regex.

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2019/04/t-sql-queries/row-pattern-recognition-in-sql

Comment: @Dai isn't that just a proposal?

Comment: @Marko I believe it's now part of the spec and SQL Server 2021 (and maybe 2019?) supports part of it.

Comment: What is your "pattern"? It seems like you're trying to reconstruct individual uses of a website, defined as starting with URL like /index or /v1/home, but using only timestamps. What happens if you have two consecutive users? Do you have a user or session ID?

Comment: @Schwern Fair point. I didn't include the user column earlier. In this case, let's assume I narrow it down to user1. The "pattern" in this case is the four consecutive rows.

Comment: So, a row should only be included in the results if the `url` only appears once for that user?

Comment: What about the sequence `a, b, c,   a, b, c, d,   a, b, c, d`?  Should `a, b, c` be in the results?

Comment: @ThomasWest It's exactly those four consecutive rows in that order?

Comment: @ThomasWest Your four consecutive rows are slightly different.

Comment: The Answer by [talegna](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1680119/talegna) to [SQL: SELECT WHERE COUNT = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22503149/12695027) is almost identical to what you want.

Comment: @MatBailie Thats a good call out. I didn't think of that but, for this example, let's just assume it's always be `a,b,c` not `a,b,c,d`

Comment: @Scratte Thanks I will checkout that post

Comment: @ThomasWest - Your requirements are becoming increasingly vague.  Please edit your question and explicitly enumerate all the use-cases that you need to deal with.  If, for example, repeated sequences are always of length 1 or 4 you can reduce the problem to returning unique URLs.  If its not that, we need to know ***exactly*** what behaviour exists in the data that you Do need to deal with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of your comments you imply that a `pattern` is simply the same url appearing more than once.

In which case, you can select urls that appear only once using simple aggregation and then filter the results with a `HAVING` clause.

```
SELECT
  user, url, MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM
  yourData
GROUP BY
  user, url
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = 1
```